# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row - Trying to do CONCAT 2 SELECT in a single MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a two SELECT statement using 2 CONCAT in 1 SELECT query.The query I have is:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.wo_number
     , a.sheet
     , a.serial
     , a.machine_code machine_group
     , c.name machine_name_ws
     , a.crew_est
     , a.manhour_est
     , a.crew_est * a.manhour_est crew_kali_manhour
     , CONCAT(
               (SELECT machine_code FROM table_b WHERE wo_number = a.wo_number AND sheet_no = a.sheet AND step = a.serial)
             ) machine_code_actual
     , d.name machine_name_actual
     , CONCAT(
               (SELECT SUM(act_hours) FROM table_b WHERE wo_number = a.wo_number AND sheet_no = a.sheet AND step = a.serial)
             ) act_hours
     , b.status_man 
  FROM table_a a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_b b 
    ON b.wo_number = a.wo_number 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_c c 
    ON c.machine_group = a.machine_code 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_c_but_used_as_d d 
    ON d.code = b.machine_code 
 WHERE a.wo_number = 'I7519009' 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id 
 ORDER 
    BY a.sheet
     , a.serial;
```

I'm getting **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row** error, I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me with this?

As always,
Any help will be much appreciated,

Thank You.

Comment: Arent you looking for group_concat? http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php. Concat is uses for combining 2 string (`field1`, `field2`) Ps: I thinks its better to use a formated query in the question

Comment: I don't think I've known about GROUP_CONCAT, can you provide the answer above the comment? thank you

Comment: Whats the think you want to receive with the concat (are the multiple machine codes with the number/ sheet/ serial?

Comment: I need to get **machine_code** and **SUM(`act_hours`)** result FROM table_b.

Comment: CONCAT? But you ain't CONCATing anything !?! And you have no aggregating functions - at least not within the same scope as the GROUP BY.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query